# How to split week start date and week end date based on custom period dates in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I need to split weeks for below period start date and end date for whole years in the calendar starting from year 1980 to 2050, period start and end dates are stored in a table.

```
Expected Result for  
1) period start date : 01-01-2020          period end date:   15-01-2020    Period code : P1        
2) period start date : 05-01-2020          period end date:   19-01-2020    Period code : P2     
3) period start date :  16-01-2020         period end date:   31-01-2020    Period code : P1     
4) period start date :  20-01-2020         period end date:   04-02-2020    Period code : P2
```

---- each period should split into 3 weeks only

```
week_Start_date  week_end_date  period_start_date period_end_date Period_code

**01-01-2020     05-01-2020     01-01-2020        15-01-2020       P1     
06-01-2020       12-01-2020     01-01-2020        15-01-2020       P1     
13-01-2020       15-01-2020     01-01-2020        15-01-2020       P1**   
05-01-2020       05-01-2020     05-01-2020        19-01-2020       P2     
06-01-2020       12-01-2020     05-01-2020        19-01-2020       P2     
13-01-2020       19-01-2020     05-01-2020        19-01-2020       P2     
**16-01-2020     19-01-2020   16-01-2020      31-01-2020           P1     
20-01-2020       26-01-2020     16-01-2020        31-01-2020       P1     
27-01-2020       31-01-2020     16-01-2020        31-01-2020       P1**   
20-01-2020       26-01-2020     20-01-2020        04-02-2020       P2     
27-01-2020       02-02-2020     20-01-2020        04-02-2020       P2     
03-02-2020       04-02-2020     20-01-2020        04-02-2020       P2
```

Custom Period table:

```
year    period_start_date   period_end_date period_code
2020    01-01-2020              15-01-2020  P1   
2020    05-01-2020              19-01-2020  P2   
2020    16-01-2020              31-01-2020  P1   
2020    20-01-2020              04-02-2020  P2   
2020    01-02-2020              15-02-2020  P1   
2020    05-02-2020              19-02-2020  P2   
2020    16-02-2020              29-02-2020  P1   
2020    20-02-2020              04-03-2020  P2   
2020    01-03-2020              15-03-2020  P1   
2020    05-03-2020              19-03-2020  P2   
2020    16-03-2020              31-03-2020  P1   
2020    20-03-2020              04-04-2020  P2   
2020    01-04-2020              15-04-2020  P1   
2020    05-04-2020              19-04-2020  P2   
2020    16-04-2020              30-04-2020  P1   
2020    20-04-2020              04-05-2020  P2   
2020    01-05-2020              15-05-2020  P1   
2020    05-05-2020              19-05-2020  P2   
2020    16-05-2020              31-05-2020  P1   
2020    20-05-2020              04-06-2020  P2
```

I have tried below on the calendar table.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[CalenderTable] a
        ,(
            SELECT min(DATE) AS week_start_date
                ,max(DATE) AS week_end_date
                ,ISOweek AS ISSWEEK
                ,year AS yyear
                ,month AS mmonth
            FROM [dbo].[dim_cal]
            GROUP BY ISOweek
                ,month
                ,year
            ) b
    WHERE a.DATE BETWEEN b.week_start_date
            AND b.week_end_date
```

I end up getting 4 weeks for a period, which is not correct for my scenario. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I would find this question much easier to follow if the dates were in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, format mentioned in above question is in DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: . . I can see that.  It just takes so much effort for me to figure out what you are really asking, that I'm not bothering to try to figure it out.

Comment: I have custom periods for every month, for each period start and end date, i have to split into weeks start date and end date for a given period start and end date, the split should be only 3 weeks as in here  4) period start date :  20-01-2020         period end date:   04-02-2020     ------ and result  is 20-01-2020       26-01-2020,    
27-01-2020       02-02-2020   ,03-02-2020       04-02-2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this peace of code worked, but got 3 duplicates in output....

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;  

DECLARE @period_start_date date, @period_end_date date, @message varchar(1000),
    @period_code nvarchar(10) ;  

PRINT '-------- Starting --------';  

DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT top (1) period_start_date , period_end_date, period_code from
[dbo].[MonthlyCalender] where period_start_date='2020-1-20' ORDER BY month_start_date; 

OPEN vendor_cursor  

--FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
---INTO @month_start_date, @month_end_date,@period_code  

 ---   PRINT @month_start_date

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
INTO @period_start_date, @period_end_date,@period_code  

      PRINT @period_start_date
      PRINT @period_end_date
      PRINT @period_code  



declare @StartDate date


 set @StartDate = @period_start_date

 declare @EndDate date

 set @EndDate = @period_end_date

declare @pd_start_date date

set @pd_start_date = @period_start_date

declare @pd_end_date date

set @pd_end_date = @period_end_date

declare @pd_code nvarchar(10)

set @pd_code=@period_code 

 declare @DateCalc date

 declare @WeekStartDate date

 set @WeekStartDate = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,@StartDate), 0)

 set @DateCalc = @StartDate

 WHILE (@WeekStartDate <= @EndDate )

 begin

insert into testrun

   select case when @StartDate > @WeekStartDate then DatePart(ww,@StartDate) else DatePart(ww,@WeekStartDate) end as WeekNum, @StartDate as StartDate, case when DATEADD(dd, 6, @WeekStartDate) > @EndDate then @EndDate else DATEADD(dd, 6, @WeekStartDate) end as EndDate,
   @pd_start_date as pd_start_date, @pd_end_date as pd_end_date,@pd_code as pd_code;

   set @WeekStartDate = DATEADD(dd, 7, @WeekStartDate)

   set @StartDate = @WeekStartDate
 END



END;

PRINT 'Done Populating week start and end dates for given periods';


CLOSE vendor_cursor  
DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;
```